# Add [redshift] synonym to [amazon-redshift] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

The other Amazon tags all seem to have appropriate synonyms. Does this one intentionally not have one or is it accidentally missed?

Comment: If you want to make them synonyms, and this is actually a request in disguise, use the [meta-tag:synonym-request] tag...